# header looks different in different broswers

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, header

I have this header here...

```
.header {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 16px;
    width: 920px;
}

.logo {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 500px;
}

.phoneNumber {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #44BAD2;
    float: left;
    font-size: 22px;
    height: 94px;
    line-height: 95px;
    width: 155px;
}

.social {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 69px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 190px;
}

.social ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.social li {
    float: left;
}
```

In google chrome it looks good, but in firefox, the left and right side are too short, you can see this at http://www.surfthecurve.ca

Here is also the html

```
 <div class="header">

<div class="social">
<ul>
<li class="facebook">
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/SurfTheCurve"></a>
</li>
<li class="twitter">
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/SurfCurveTutor"></a>
</li>
<li class="email">
<a target="_blank" href="mailto:info@surfthecurve.ca?subject=Website Enquiry"></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!--social-->

<div class="logo">
<a href="http://surfthecurve.ca/"><img src="http://surfthecurve.ca/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/logo.jpg" width="500" border="0" /></a>
</div><!--logo-->

<div class="phoneNumber">
647.390.3070
</div><!--phoneNumber-->


</div><!--header-->
```

Comment: Try fixing these [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsurfthecurve.ca%2F) first. That is often a source of inconsistency. If that doesn't help you find your problem give us an update.

Comment: looks exactly same on my chrome and firefox????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the floats there. You can use clear:both or use the [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) method.

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Ummm didnt appear to work, I added the code you posted by it did not work....do I do anything to the code you posted?

Comment: Add the clearfix code to the CSS at the bottom.
Modify class="header" to class="header clearfix".